# Use of copyrighted material

Tags: support

Is it allowed to make pdf 'snapshots' of images included in copyrighted scientific articles to back up my answer (e.g. Biology or Cognitive Sciences SE)? At the risk to be verbally nuked - I have to say I have done this a few times. Advise on the legal aspects of uploading visual images of copyrighted material is welcomed. Obviously I am more than willing to remove any such snapshots from my existing answers when necessary.

**EDIT**: As a side note in response to comments: I do cite the image sources, with links and all (John Doe et al, 2010 + attached weblink to article on publisher's website when copyrighted and not available full-text online). So the authors of the article will likely be OK with me posting their images + citation, it's the publisher's copyright ownership that is of concern to me. Note that I obtain these articles from my uni library. So they are not freely available full text on the internet.

**EDIT2**: The question [What is proper etiquette when someone posts copyrighted material?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48364/what-is-proper-etiquette-when-someone-posts-copyrighted-material) touches on my question, but deals with *full-text* artciles that *someone else* has made public, possibly infringing copyrights. My question is different, as it concerns reproduction and uploading **image material** to **imgur** ***by me***, while citing the material properly. When I would publish such a snapshot in a journal, I typically **have to ask approval** from the publisher of the original article. My question now is: What does it mean when I upload copyrighted material to imgur?

Related questions: [imgur, copyrighted images from the web, and imgur accounts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64005/imgur-copyrighted-images-from-the-web-and-imgur-accounts) and [Answers that direct towards material that infringes copyright](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49427/answers-that-direct-towards-material-that-infringes-copyright)

Comment: actually this seem an interesting question to me, for two specific reasons: 1) the answer may need to take in account the laws in the poster country; 2) the SE Collaborative Common license should have effect on those images too, therefore requiring further analysis of the problem.

Comment: If those articles are published, you'd better quote them and provide a bibliography link, as it is made in scientific articles. It falls under fair use, as it is practicised in all scientific articles worldwide (at least, I'm not aware of any country on the worlds, where the praxis looks otherwise). Scientific articles are meant to be quoted. However, it doesn't necessarily apply to the media on which they are published, so photographing the magazines can potentially fall under other category.

Comment: @ВГДЕЖЅZЗИІКЛМНОПҀРСТȢѸФХ - I do cite properly. I do not photograph, but I do snapshot the pdf now and then. Re-producing an image like this when publishing an article does require approval from the publisher. My concern is whether I can do it at SE without publisher's consent. I have edited the question in response to your comment.

Comment: @gnat - I saw that post, and it doesn't exactly cover my question as that post deals with *full-text* material *someone else* has shared. I must say that it is practice I do not mind too much about, as it's the other person's responsibility to providing it to the web, and the reader's responsibility to deal with it.

Comment: frankly I think that [answers over here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114919/165773) cover both your and that other question pretty well. "In essence, you are free to moderate the site for content how you see fit... but you are not required to do so. You are not DMCA agents ..."

Comment: @gnat - OK, a last comment here - I am not talking from a mod perspective (I'm not) and what is a DMCA agent? :)

Comment: me and you are unlikely these agents (their job is to look out and report possible copyright violations)

Comment: @gnat - very well :) Thanks a lot. Should I delete this question, since it is, arguably, a suspected duplicate?

Comment: duplicate doesn't imply that deletion is necessary, see [Dr. Strangedupe: Or, How I Learned to Stop Worrying And Love Duplication](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/)