# Do we answer questions that depend on illegal software?

Tags: discussion

Do we answer questions which require workarounds for illegal software?  Example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754093/how-do-i-integrate-uac-into-my-vb6-program) (see comments on the answer by *csauve*).  On one of the questions, the poster specifically states that he's using "Visual Basic 6 Portable" which is an illegal copy of VS.  He specifically notes that an answer doesn't work for him because he's using an illegal version of the software.  Similar to the following two questions:

- [Suggesting software that infringes copyright](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23818/suggesting-software-that-infringes-copyright)
- [Do we answer questions that may have malicious intent?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27177/do-we-answer-questions-that-may-have-malicious-intent)

Comment: Remove the reference to "VB6 Portable", is his question still valid?

Comment: It's a valid question, but he said a valid answer to his question didn't work because it didn't work for his illegal software.

Comment: Replace "illegal software" with "some strange version specific requirement". Would you close it as too localized or leave the question open for others to answer?

Comment: The problem is not so much the question, but rather the lack of an accepted answer.  He got several valid answers to his question, but hasn't accepted them because they don't work with his illegal copy of vb6.  All legal copies work just fine with the given answers.

Comment: @mydogisbox: The checkbox belongs to the OP. They can accept an answer for any reason or no reason, or not accept an answer at all. The lack of a checkbox is not a satisfactory reason to close the question, regardless of the cause.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Right, except that his question should include that it has to work for Visual Basic 6 Portable (he states as much in the comments) and VB6 Portable is illegal software.  If it was simply that he didn't like the current answers that is fine, but he's asking for help using his illegal software.

Comment: I don't see any such request there, other than one comment the OP made in passing, the answer to which is "well, find a legitimate copy of VB6 then."

Comment: Does even MS *care* about this?  VB6 is EOL.  Whoever wasted their time on this needs to get cracking on "Visual Studio Portable."

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It doesn't matter how he procured VB6<strike>, you flag it for moderator attention because he's using VB6</strike>. If the original poster was reasonably intelligent about his predicament, he could have stated that his machine appeared not to have the files.

There is no sense in worrying about those details while answering questions on StackOverflow; we're not Intellectual Property Police.

If you feel his question cannot be reasonably answered due to the original poster's specific circumstances: *vote to close as Too Localized*.

Comment: +1... However, the question (and its answers) are still valid for those folks that have a legitimate VB6 environment.

Comment: Thanks, rephrased my last sentence to say what I meant to mean to say.

Comment: +1, we answer to the circumstances presented, not to how they got the platform (why do we care?). A valid question is a valid question. Unfortunately, many of these are too localized simply because they can't be reproduced easily.